# how to clear https and httpss error on opencart 3.0.2.0 version

Tags: ssl, opencart, opencart-3

I have installed the SSL on my OpenCart project all the page are running on https except category and product pages it's running on httpss?

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
>
> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.xxxyyzz.in/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_60'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'httpss://www.xxxyyzz.in/image/catalog/AjaxLoader.gif'. This content
>   should also be served over HTTPS."

only on my category pages all the links are runs over httpss i dont where can i change?

```
class ControllerProductCategory extends Controller {

    public function index() {    
        $this->load->language('product/category'); 
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {

            $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];

        } else {

            $filter = '';

        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
        }
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );
        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $url = '';
            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }
            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }
            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }
            $path = '';
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
            $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);
            foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
                if (!$path) {
                    $path = (int)$path_id;
                } else {
                    $path .= '_' . (int)$path_id;
                }
                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);
                if ($category_info) {
                    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                        'text' => $category_info['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path . $url)
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }
        $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);
        if ($category_info) {
            $this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
            $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
            $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);
            $data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];
            $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
            // Set the last category breadcrumb
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(

                'text' => $category_info['name'],

                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'])

            );



            if ($category_info['image']) {

                $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_height'));

            } else {

                $data['thumb'] = '';

            }



            $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');



            $url = '';



            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {

                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {

                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {

                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {

                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];

            }



            $data['categories'] = array();



            $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);



            foreach ($results as $result) {

                $filter_data = array(

                    'filter_category_id'  => $result['category_id'],

                    'filter_sub_category' => true

                );



                $data['categories'][] = array(

                    'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),

                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)

                );

            }



            $data['products'] = array();



            $filter_data = array(

                'filter_category_id' => $category_id,

                'filter_filter'      => $filter,

                'sort'               => $sort,

                'order'              => $order,

                'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,

                'limit'              => $limit

            );



            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);



            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);



            foreach ($results as $result) {

                $text_percent = '';

                if ($result['image']) {

                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));

                } else {

                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));

                }



                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {

                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);

                    $price_num = $this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));

                } else {

                    $price = false;

                    $price_num= false;

                }



                if ((float)$result['special']) {

                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);

                    $special_num = $this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));

                } else {

                    $special = false;

                    $special_num = false;

                }



                if ($special_num && $price_num) {

                    $percent =  round(($price_num-$special_num)/$price_num*100,0);

                    $text_percent =  sprintf($this->language->get('text_label_sale'), $percent);

                }



                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {

                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);

                } else {

                    $tax = false;

                }





                $data['products'][] = array(

                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],

                    'thumb'       => $image,

                    'name'        => $result['name'],

                    'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',

                    'price'       => $price,


                    'text_percent'  => $text_percent,

                    'tax'         => $tax,

                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,



                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)

                );

            }



            $url = '';



            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {

                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {

                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];

            }



            $data['sorts'] = array();



            $data['sorts'][] = array(

                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),

                'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',

                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)

            );



            $data['sorts'][] = array(

                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),

                'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',

                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)

            );



            $data['sorts'][] = array(

                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),

                'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',

                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)

            );



            $data['sorts'][] = array(

                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),

                'value' => 'p.price-ASC',

                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)

            );



            $data['sorts'][] = array(

                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),

                'value' => 'p.price-DESC',

                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)

            );









            $url = '';



            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {

                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {

                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {

                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];

            }



            $data['limits'] = array();



            $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));



            sort($limits);



            foreach($limits as $value) {

                $data['limits'][] = array(

                    'text'  => $value,

                    'value' => $value,

                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=' . $value)

                );

            }



            $url = '';



            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {

                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {

                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {

                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {

                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];

            }



            $pagination = new Pagination();

            $pagination->total = $product_total;

            $pagination->page = $page;

            $pagination->limit = $limit;

            $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');



            $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();



            $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));



            // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

            if ($page == 1) {

                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id']), 'canonical');

            } else {

                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. $page), 'canonical');

            }



            if ($page > 1) {

                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . (($page - 2) ? '&page='. ($page - 1) : '')), 'prev');

            }



            if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {

                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. ($page + 1)), 'next');

            }



            $data['sort'] = $sort;

            $data['order'] = $order;

            $data['limit'] = $limit;



            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');



            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');

            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');

            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');

            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');

            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');



            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));

        } else {

            $url = '';



            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {

                $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {

                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {

                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {

                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {

                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];

            }



            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {

                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];

            }



            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(

                'text' => $this->language->get('text_error'),

                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', $url)

            );



            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));



            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');



            $this->response->addHeader($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');



            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');

            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');

            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');

            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');

            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');



            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('error/not_found', $data));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It appears that there is a typo where an extra "s" got added on the end of "https" somewhere.

Comment: hi andrew i checked all the files httpss not came i am worked on opencart 3.0.2.0 version

Comment: If you open the page `https://www.xxxyyzz.in/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_60` in a browser and view the page source (often it's <ctrl>U to see the source) then you will be able to search in that and find the `httpss`. It could be generated by JavaScript, so you would then have to find the script which generated the URL.

Comment: its a opencart framework so we can find the these kind of url andrew

Comment: @Sri Could you share your category page code?

Answer (score 0):

My version: 3.0.3.3

**Access the path:**
storage/modification/catalog/controller/product

**Search this or similar:**
$base_url = str_replace('http', 'https', $this->config->get('config_url'));

**Add after this line:**
$base_url = str_replace('httpss', 'https', $base_url);